# Проблема при установке python-social-auth на сайт с Django

Tags: python, django

При обработке данного запроса вылетает ошибка

```
url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
```

> site-packages/social/utils.py", line 8, in  [Wed Jul 01
>   19:01:02 2015] [error] [client 5.254.65.101:9114]     import six [Wed
>   Jul 01 19:01:02 2015] [error] [client 5.254.65.101:9114] ImportError:
>   **No module named six**

Проблема в том, что этот модуль благополучно установлен и спокойно вызывается через `import six`

Установку производил с помощью `pip install`

все настройки брал из [примеров](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/examples/django_example/example/settings.py)

Comment: `virtualenv` используете?